# How to replace JSON key value?

Tags: json, powershell

```
{"enable"=false,
"datatype"="DB",
"report"=false}
```

I need to change the `enable` value to `true`.
As now I am using the following code:

```
(Get-Content 'C:\Shibi\Basic.json') -replace 'false', 'true' | Set-Content 'C:\Shibi\Basic.json'
```

Comment: What is wrong with the code?

Comment: Just a quick note, but as posted that's not JSON -- JSON uses `:` to separate keys and values.

Comment: In the above code its replacing all the false value as true but i need to change only Enable keys value as true

Comment: @jeroenMostert can you ple guid me for this how to seprate the key and value in json and change the value as true for specfic keyby using powershell

Comment: If you had *actual* JSON, PowerShell could easily handle it with the `ConvertFrom-Json` and `ConvertTo-Json` cmdlets -- try `$j = ConvertTo-Json @{enable=false; datatype="DB"}; $x = ConvertFrom-Json $j; $x.enable = $true; ConvertTo-Json $x`. Quick and easy!

Comment: Since this is NOT Json, why not simply do `-replace '"enable"=false', '"enable"=true'` ?

Comment: @jeroenMostert but i am facing following this error using this code with adding the file name  PS C:\Users\spalanisamy>   $filePath = "C:\Shibi\Basic.json"
PS C:\Users\shibi> $j = ConvertTo-Json @{$filePath}; $x = ConvertFrom-Json $j; $x.enable = $true; ConvertTo-Json $
x
Missing '=' operator after key in hash literal.
At line:1 char:33
+ $j = ConvertTo-Json @{$filePath} <<<< ; $x = ConvertFrom-Json $j; $x.enable = $true; ConvertTo-Json $x
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingEqualsInHashLiteral

Comment: You can always [edit] your question to provide more details; posting a lot of code in comments gets pretty heinous (as you've noticed). The short of it is that to convert a file with JSON contents, you need to provide the result of `Get-Content` (i.e. `Get-Content basic.json | ConvertTo-Json`), not try to stuff the file name in a hashtable (that's what the `@{}` syntax does).

Comment: @Theo I have tried -replace '"enable"=false', '"enable"=true' this but there no changes happen in my file

Comment: For testing, always first save do a **new file** and inspect the result there. Right now, you are overwriting your source file with various tries, so there is no telling what the original looks like anymore. P.S. Why are you calling it JSON?, what process created this?

Comment: @theo I need to update the Json file value as true for speific key by using power shell in existing file.

Comment: Sure, I understand the question, but as @JeroenMostert already explained, your input file is **NOT** JSON. You either treat is as text and do the replace I've suggested, or you convert it to valid JSON first by replacing all `=` into `:` and use Jeroen's approach.

Comment: Thanks @theo can you please suggest me link or code for Convert json in power shell

Comment: Um... that is not hard to google I imaging.. look for `ConvertTo-Json` and `ConvertFrom-Json`

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to work with a text file rather than a true JSON structure, you can use the `*-Content` commands with the `-replace` operator.

```
(Get-Content 'C:\Shibi\Basic.json') -replace '"enable"=false','"enable"=true' | Set-Content
```

**Note:** [Set-Content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content?view=powershell-6) will update the Basic.json file with the replaced data.

You can add the `-Raw` switch to [Get-Content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-6) to preserve white space or newline characters of the original file.

Answer (score 0):

If you put the content in JSON format like other people suggested, this solution worked for me:

```
$jsonstr = Get-Content thecontent.json | ConvertFrom-Json
$jsonstr.enable = "true"
$json = $jsonstr | ConvertTo-Json
echo $json > thecontent.json
Get-Content thecontent.json
```